# powershell csom document set welcome page view

Tags: powershell, csom, view, document-set, welcome-page

[image]I am try to set document set  welcome page view with powershell csom  with out any luck. Does anyone have an idea how to do it

```
$password=""
$username=""
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Import-Module Sharegate



$siteUrl = "https://sharepoint.com/sites/projects/"

write-host "Connecting to SharePoint "$siteUrl
$pwd =  convertto-securestring $password -asplaintext -force
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl) 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $pwd)
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials

$web=$ctx.web;
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
write-host $web.title
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents")
$contentypee=$list.ContentTypes
$ctx.Load($contentypee)
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

 Foreach($ct in $contentypee){
  if($ct.name -eq 'Record'){
     $ctrecord=$ct;
     Write-Host  "list title"  $list.title
     Write-Host  "contenttype name is "  $ctrecord.Name
     Write-Host  "content type id "  $ctrecord.ID
   }
 }
 $ctrecord1=$contentypee.GetById($ctrecord.ID)
 $ctx.Load($ctrecord1)
 $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: No error, but I can't go further ,don't find any cmdlet like Setwelcomepage or something

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ecc0b2e4-8661-420a-bdf5-d7af13567be2/change-welcome-page-of-site-collection-using-powershell?forum=sharepointadminprevious) is technet answer I found of someone trying to achieve the same thing.

In case the link ever goes down, here is the answer in question:

> You can certainly do this with PowerShell! You need to dive into the
>   object model a little bit to accomplish this. Please keep in mind that
>   the Welcome page is a relative link to your site.
>
> Say your current site collection welcome page is
>   http://yoursitecollection/Pages/Home.aspx and you want to change it to
>   http://yoursitecollection/Pages/NewWelcomePage.aspx.
>
> $assignment = Start-SPAssignment
>
> $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://yoursitecollectionurl" AssignmentCollection $assignment
>
> $rootFolder = $web.RootFolder
>
> $rootFolder.WelcomePage =
>   "Pages/NewWelcomePage.aspx"
>
> $rootFolder.Update()
>
> Stop-SPAssignment
>   $assignment
>
> Another note - if there are spaces in your .aspx page file name, then
>   simply type spaces (i.e. you don't need to include the url encoded %20
>   for spaces). For example you could change the line above to:
>
> $rootFolder.WelcomePage = "Pages/New Welcome Page.aspx"
>
> I hope this helps,
>
> Craig

Comment: Thanks  but i am looking for Document-set  welcome page view

Comment: Apologies, I misread your post in my haste. Could the above work if you changed the context of $rootfolder to that of your document set?

Comment: My knowlage is limmited but i dont thing document-set has rootfolder property

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Get welcome page from document set
- Get webpart manager from welcome page
- Get the document list Webpart
- Set the view on the Webpart

No idea, how you can change the default on the document set configuration

Comment: Following post looks like a better solution:

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9d0951d3-61d3-4982-95d4-246e96aff4db/how-to-set-document-set-welcome-page-view-property-via-powershell?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: The link to that solution is server side powershell so not particularly helpful in this case(the question is asking for a solution using CSOM powershell)

Answer (score 0):

that is only doable in sharepoint on premises, here is an explanation for [programmatically setting up the document set default view on a list](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Provisioning-Schema/issues/190)

=> If you want a **workaround for sharepoint online**, please use this [powershell docset welcomepage view](https://github.com/holylander/manage-sharepoint-pnp-powershell/blob/master/src/lists/change_docset_welcomepageview-IE_scrapper.psm1) setter and [follow this example](https://github.com/holylander/manage-sharepoint-pnp-powershell/blob/master/examples/change_docset_welcomepageview_in_list.ps1)